# Show that $(C^n_0)^2 +( C^n_1)^2 + (C^n_2)^2+\dots+(C^n_n)^2 = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ using binomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics

Using the expansion of $$(1+x)^n$$
Show that
$$(C^n_0)^2 +( C^n_1)^2 + (C^n_2)^2+\dots+(C^n_n)^2 = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$
My turn
$$(1+x)^n = 1 + n x + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!} x^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} x^3+\dots+x^n$$ 
Put $x=1$
$$2^n = 1 +n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!} +\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}  +\dots +1$$
And the R.H.S of the required can be written as $C^{2n}_n$.

But I have stopped here!

Comment: Consider the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^n (x+1)^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle \frac {(2n)!}{(n!)^2} = C^{2n}_n$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^{2n}$.

And $(1+x)^{2n} = \left( (1+x)^n \right)^2 = (1+x)^n(1+x)^n$

Does that help you ?

Comment: Thanks iam gonna try it @gandalf

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom{2n}{n}=[x^n](1+x)^{2n}=[x^n](1+x)^n(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}=\sum_k\binom{n}{k}^2.$$